# Why is the skim_with() function returning double output?

Tags: r, summary, skimr

I am using the following code to provide customized summary statistics of a generic dataframe:

```
library(skimr)
my_skim <- skim_with(base = sfl(n_missing = n_missing),
  numeric = sfl(hist =NULL , range = range, iqr = iqr, skew=skewness, cv = cv))

my_skim(df)
```

I don't understand why `my_skim()` returns twice the summary for each variable. Can you help solve this problem?